# Approximate linear time algorithm for minimum k-cut

Tags: ds.algorithms

I need to approximately and quickly solve a minimum k-cut problem for n=2^14 and k=512.

It seems that the 2-approximation algorithm given by Saran and Vazirani which needs to solve O(n) instances of max-flow problem will make the overall algorithm take O(n^2m) time. Though we expect the graph to be sparse, this seems prohibitive.

Is there a O(n) time algorithm with possible compromise on the approximation ratio?

Thank you.